# MySQL query not working

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

On my site, users have a 'to-do' list. After obtaining a minimum level of achievement on a quiz, that quiz will be removed from the users' to-do. The code below works correctly for products, but not for any quizzes listed via the 'BusinessRelationship'.

```
def not_quizzed_things
   taken_company_ids = quizzes_taken.select{|q| q.thing_type == 'BusinessRelationship'}.map{|q| q.thing_id}.uniq
   conds = "business_relationships.from_company_id = ? and (business_relationships.legit_quiz_questions_count + c.legit_quiz_questions_count) > 0"
   args = [company_id]
   unless taken_company_ids.blank?
     conds += " and c.id not in (?)"
     args << taken_company_ids
  end

  quiz_companies = BusinessRelationship.find(:all, :joins => "join companies c on c.id = business_relationships.to_company_id", :conditions => [conds]+args, :order => "id", :limit => 0)
  quiz_companies = [company] + quiz_companies unless company.legit_quiz_questions_count <= 0 || quizzes_taken.select{|q| q.thing_type == 'Company'}.map{|q| q.thing}.include?(company)
  n = 20 - quiz_companies.size

  taken_products_retailer_ids = quizzes_taken.select{|q| q.thing_type == 'ProductsRetailer'}.map{|q| q.thing_id}.uniq
  conds = "products_retailers.company_id = ? and (p.legit_quiz_questions_count + products_retailers.legit_quiz_questions_count) > 0"
  args = [company_id]
  unless taken_products_retailer_ids.blank?
    conds += " and products_retailers.id not in (?)"
    args << taken_products_retailer_ids
  end
quiz_products_retailers = ProductsRetailer.find(:all, :joins => "join products p on p.id = products_retailers.product_id", :conditions => [conds]+args, :order => "id", :limit => n)
quiz_companies + quiz_products_retailers
end
```

Console results:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :007 > y u.quizzes_taken.last
--- !ruby/object:Quiz 
attributes: 
  thing_id: "213"
  created_at: 2012-06-09 20:07:32
  end_time: 2012-06-09 20:07:56
  current_attempt_id: 
  thing_type: BusinessRelationship
  updated_at: 2012-06-09 20:07:56
  order: "2388,2389,2390,2391"
  id: "467"
  correct_count: "4"
  user_id: "392"
  attempt_count: "4"
  start_time: 2012-06-09 20:07:32
attributes_cache: {}
```

Any thoughts or suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would look at your debug window to see the exact SQL that was sent to the DB, and see why your query is not coming out as you expect.  Work from your database back to your code.